# How to encode special HTML character without HTML entities in Java

Tags: java

I want to encode only HTML characters not entities.

For example, I want to contert:

```
<div>1 < 2</div>
```

to

```
<div>1 &lt; 2</div>
```

I try StringEscapeUtils but it transforms all to

```
&lt;div&gt;1 &lt; 2&lt;/div&gt;
```

Comment: how can you tell which `<` to encode and which one not to encode? Can you describe the rule that decides what to do?

Comment: Just do it on the strings and not the tags?

Comment: Yes just do it on string not tag html. I want just encode special characters between html tag. I have <div>1 < 2</div> and I just want <div>1 &lt; 2</div>